# How to center and space boxes in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, modifier

I have a grid with three items.
I would like all my boxes to be vertically centered with spaces/padding in between.

Currently, this code outputs my boxes to be spaced apart(with padding), but if I change to `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center`, it centers my boxes but removes the padding. Is there a way that I could have both?

```
@Composable
fun TopicGrid(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(1),
        verticalArrangement =  Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_large)),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(DataSource.topics) { topic ->
            TopicCard(topic)
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to change this into:

```
@Composable
fun TopicGrid(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(1),
        verticalArrangement =  Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_large)),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(DataSource.topics) { topic ->
            TopicCard(topic)
        }
    }
}
```

But all this does is center my boxes without spacing them.
I've tried using spacers as well but doesn't seem to work for me.

Expected result,

[image]

Comment: you can try using ```contentPadding``` in ```LazyVerticalGrid```

Comment: can you add a picture of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @ChiragThummar, contentPadding creates padding around all my elements, but not between the elements themselves.

Comment: how exactly you want your screen? can you share it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hUzCIBV

like so. thanks for all your help!

Comment: Why are you using a `LazyVerticalGrid ` for 3 items placed vertically? `Column` or `LazyColumn` are better suitable for this use-case.

Comment: @Abhimanyu, I'm just using this for a first iteration, I will add other columns later :) Thanks for your advice though!